# Authentication Filters in Jersey 1.x

Tags: java, rest, jersey-1.0

Is there an alternative to @NameBinding annotation in Jersey 1.x

I have developed a REST based Server API using Jersey 1.x but, need to implement Filters only for certain Requests.

On researching found that, @NameBinding  performs the job perfectly. However , my whole project is Jersey 1.x based, and hence I am not able to bring this functionality.

Thanks